# What is the difference between there two sections of code(about python GIL)?

Tags: python, gil

**Fragment code 1**:

```
before = time()
urls = ['https://google.com'] * 5
for url in urls:
    thread1 = Thread(target=get_content, args=(url,))
    thread1.start()
    thread1.join()
after = time()
print(after - before)
```

To run the code, The result is `5.740652799606323`

The Threading graph is :
[image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZivq.png)

**Fragment code 2**:

```
before = time()
thread1 = Thread(target=get_content, args=('https://google.com',))
thread2 = Thread(target=get_content, args=('https://google.com',))
thread3 = Thread(target=get_content, args=('https://google.com',))
thread4 = Thread(target=get_content, args=('https://google.com',))
thread5 = Thread(target=get_content, args=('https://google.com',))
thread1.start()
thread2.start()
thread3.start()
thread4.start()
thread5.start()
thread1.join()
thread2.join()
thread3.join()
thread4.join()
thread5.join()
after = time()
print(after - before)
```

To run the code, the result is :`1.102950096130371`

The Threading graph is :
[image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFHYH.png)


**I think the result will be similar. But the finally result is not. Why?**

**Anyone can help me to explain this?**

Comment: The first example starts a thread, and then joins it (waits for it to finish) before starting the next.  The second example starts them all, then waits for them all to finish.  It's basically sequential vs. parallel (or consecutive vs. concurrent).

Comment: I removed the gil tag from your question because this simply has nothing to do with the GIL but a misunderstanding of how `threadobj.join()` works.  Is there a reason you've put it back and edited your title?

Comment: Your answer is very useful, thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `thread1.join()` waits until the thread is finished. You have that in the loop so that means that the loop will not go to the next iteration until the 1st request is completed.

Essentially you have "killed" the multi threading idea and forced the program to execute the requests one at a time.

One way to change would be to do something like this:

```
before = time()
urls = ['https://google.com'] * 5
threads = []
for url in urls:
    thread1 = Thread(target=get_content, args=(url,))
    thread1.start()
    threads.append(thread1)
[t.join() for t in threads]
after = time()
print(after - before)
```

Comment: Why are you making a list of `None`s (just to throw it out)?

Comment: @jedwards because just ommiting the `[]` in `t.join() for t in threads` is not legal syntax and the other option is to make it two lines. I'm also not trying to optimize here, just show a point.

Comment: `for t in threads: t.join()` can be on one line, and doesn't create a list.

Answer (score 2):

In the first snippet, you *actually wait for each thread to finish **first**,* before you start another thread. You basically run it *serially* instead of parallel.

```
for url in urls:
    thread1 = Thread(target=get_content, args=(url,))
    thread1.start()
    thread1.join()
```

What you probably want to do when working with threads, is saving each thread in a container (list), start all the threads, and then wait on for all of them to finish.

```
ths = []
for url in urls:
    thread1 = Thread(target=get_content, args=(url,))
    thread1.start()
    ths.append(thread1)

for t in ths:
    t.join()
```

This code actually does what you *second snippet* does, just with a loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
for url in urls:
    thread1 = Thread(target=get_content, args=(url,))
    thread1.start()
    thread1.join()
```

Your `.join` is inside the `for` loop so it will start and join first before moving to the next thread. You should have a second loop after that to join them instead.